# Aspnet MVC 4 routing challenges

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I want customized routing based on Department Name and Product Name. for example /mobiles/nokia-6303

when i am calling products page it's working fine. when i am calling other than product page like Home page by default following controller and action method is executing

```
defaults: new { controller = "ContentPage", action = "ProductDetail" }
```

how to avoid this problem?

```
routes.MapRoute(
name: "ProductDetailsPage",
url: "/{DepartmentName}/{ProductName}",
defaults: new { controller = "ContentPage", action = "ProductDetail" }
);  

routes.MapRoute(
name: "Default",
url: "{controller}/{action}",
defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
);
```

Thanks in advance
Rajesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i have fixed this issue using routing config itself, please find the below code.

```
foreach (var d in departmentTranslation)
{
    routes.MapRoute(
    "ContentPage" + d.Name,
    d.Name + "/{ProductName}",
    new
        {
            controller = "ContentPage",
            action = "ProductDetails",
            id = d.DepartmentId,
            ProductName = UrlParameter.Optional
        });
}
```

Comment: we have more than 100 departments, for each department we are create one route. is this makesense?

Answer (score 2):

Your routes are exactly the same. It's impossible to differentiate between `/DepartmentName/ProductName` and `/Controller/Action`. You need something else in the URL in order to differentiate between the two things, e.g.:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "ProductDetailsPage",
    url: "/Products/{DepartmentName}/{ProductName}",
    defaults: new { controller = "ContentPage", action = "ProductDetail" }
);
```

And then navigate to /products/departmentname/productname

Comment: Thanks for your reply, if i am using /Products/{DepartmentName}/{ProductName} our SEO team is not accepting. they are telling this is not a SEO friendly URL.

Comment: @RajeshGK Well, you can't have two identical routes pointing at different places. It doesn't make sense. You have to have URLs with different formats. The only other alternative you have is to host a separate MVC app on a subdomain: products.site.com/department/product

Comment: is there any option for validating incoming URL through database to check {DepartmentName}/{ProductName} is matching. and ignore ProductDetailsPage routing?

Comment: now i realized above solution is not going to work, we are registering routing configuration in Application_start so it's not possible to validate each request.

Comment: You may be able to write a custom route handler that will check each request against the database and change what controller it resolves based on the result. Sounds pretty horrid though. Have a look here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/595520/MvcRouteHandler-and-MvcHandler-in-ASP-NET-MVC-Fram

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a slight modification to Ant P's excellent suggestion would be to place the text in between department name and product name?

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "ProductDetailsPage",
    url: "/{DepartmentName}/Products/{ProductName}",
    defaults: new { controller = "ContentPage", action = "ProductDetail" }
);
```

Or to have details afterwards:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "ProductDetailsPage",
    url: "/{DepartmentName}/{ProductName}/details",
    defaults: new { controller = "ContentPage", action = "ProductDetail" }
);
```

Either of these URL approaches might get past your 'SEO team', since it is including soemwhat relevant information within the URL.

Answer (score 0):

As other answers mention, the routing system can't differentiate between `{controller}/{action}` and `{DepartmentName}/{ProductName}`.

You can solve this problem by adding a [constraint to a route](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.route.constraints.aspx). If a constraint isn't fulfilled, the route won't match the URL. You will probably need to create a custom implementation of IRouteConstraint. I see two options:

- Create a constraint for the {controller}/{action} route, that will contain a list of possible names of controllers, that should be use the default URL pattern
- Create a constraint for the {DepartmentName}/{ProductName} route, that will check the database (or some in-memory cache) whether department name and product name match some product

Comment: finally i have fixed this issue using routing config itself, please find the below code.